# Are there any web services providing country border data?

Tags: java, google-maps-api, android, web-service

I am an Android developer (working in Java) and want to write a geographical quiz game. The quiz will need a list of countries and will randomly choose one to highlight on a map (probably using Google Maps). Then the user can type in the name of the country.

What web services are available that will give me the polygon data of the border of a given country?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Google Fusion tables version](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=424206) (see [related blog post](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2011/02/natural-earth-vectors-in-cloud.html)) of the [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) world boundaries dataset with the Google Maps API, as in these answers:

- [Country boundries using Google Map API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10890455/386205)
- [Google Maps V3: Draw German State Polygons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10875909/386205)

Comment: I should have qualified that I'm programming in Java on Android. AFAIK, this limits me to Google Maps v2.

Comment: Still, I'd think you should be able to use this data, it just might be a little more work. I don't do Android development myself but maybe someone else who does can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can download this data for free. 
Use this link:

http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/world-map-data-download.php

Comment: I am looking for a service that I can access programatically from my app so that it isn't overly bloated.